# After dismissing VC on an upside-down portrait mode the main VC shows up as a normal portrait

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, rotation

Supposing I have a view controller I'm showing like this on an iPad:

```
[self presentViewController:self.someViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and dismissing like this:

```
[self.someViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

When I open the app on upside-down portrait mode it looks ok, then present the VC which also supports the upside-down portrait and then when I dismiss it, the main VC changes orientation to normal portait mode. Why does it happen? Where should I set it to make it adjust automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there was UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait returned by preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation and I fixed this as following:

```
 - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
//changed this:
//    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
//to this:
return [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
}
```

Does it seem to look like a reasonable solution?